# Como travar submissão através de uma requisição ajax por um evento bind() em botão

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

A requisição ajax, me retorna "1" ou "0". Toda vez que clico no botão avançar, porém ele não está bloqueando a submissão. Como devo fazer para validar os valores, caso tenha uma resposta "0", ele deve travar o método de submissão:

```
DDWFrontEnd = function() {

    self.checkUsedTimeSlot = function() {

    var ddw_order_date = self.$ddw_order_date.val();
    var retorno = false;
        if (self.timeSlotId != null) {
           var promise = $.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: 'ajax.php?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
                       async: false,
                       cache: false,
                       data : {
                           ddw_order_date: ddw_order_date,
                           id_timeslot: self.timeSlotId
                       },
                       dataType : "json",
                       complete: function(d) {

                       },
                       success: function(jsonData) {
                          return jsonData;
                       },

                    });
           return promise;
        }
    }

    $('input.avancar').bind('click', function(e) {

         var bool = self.checkUsedTimeSlot().then(
           function(returnBool) {
              return (returnBool == '1');
         });

        if (!bool) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
           return true;
    });

}

$(function() {
     ddw = new DDWFrontEnd();
});
```

[**Aqui tem um JSFIDDLE do exemplo do problema**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/58fseb5c/)

Comment: Boa noite , bicho ao invés de colocar return jsonData , lá dentro do success do Ajax , tente validar naquele local, ates de usar o retur jsonData , faça a verificação e so depois o retorno, caso seja 0 return false , caso seja verdadeira você retorna o jsonData , veja se isso lhe ajuda .

Comment: Boa noite, antes de retornar no JSON, valide. Se for `0`, `return false;`

Comment: Como poderia fazer isso, publique uma resposta para eu poder visualizar sua solução.

Comment: Me passa mais informações do teu JSON de retor da função success dentro do teu ajax , assim eu poderei publicar um resposta adequada ao seu problema.

Comment: nem é um JSON é só "1" e "0", nada mais que isso... No console.log(jsonData), ele me retorna "1" ou "0". Só que não está retornando true ou false, no click do botão, mesmo fazendo a requisição ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o valor que estava vindo no console log era: `' "1"'` ou `' "0"'`. Então resolvi o problema da seguinte maneira:

```
self.checkUsedTimeSlot = function() {

         var ddw_order_date = self.$input_ddw_order_date.val();

       if (self.timeSlotId != null) {
           return $.ajax({
                   type: 'GET',
                   url: 'ajax.php?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
                   async: false,
                   cache: false,
                   data : {
                       ddw_order_date: ddw_order_date,
                       id_timeslot: self.timeSlotId
                   }
          });
       }
}
```

Aqui no botão:

```
      $('input.avancar').bind("click",  function (e) {
            var promise =   self.checkUsedTimeSlot()
                                .responseText
                                .replace(/\s/gi,'');
            if(promise != undefined) {
                var pr = eval(promise);
                pr = (pr == 1); 
            }
            if(!pr) {
               e.preventDefault();
               return false;
            } else {
              return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Então como eu não entendi muito bem seu JSON eu fiz um de exemplo

meuPHP.php ficaria assim :

```
$bonito = "SIM";
$meuJson = Array('mensagem'=>'');

if($bonito == "SIM"){
    $meuJson['mensagem'] = 1;
}else{
    $meuJson['mensagem'] = 0;
}

echo json_encode($urls);
```

meu JS ficariam assim:

```
var promise = $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'ajax.php?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
     async: false,
     cache: false,
     data : {ddw_order_date: ddw_order_date,id_timeslot: self.timeSlotId},
     dataType : "json",
     success: function(jsonData) {
            if(!jsonData.mensagem || jsonData.mensagem == 0){
                return false;
            }else{return jsonData;}
     },
     complete: function(d) {

     },
```

});

Já no seu caso acontece o seguinte:

```
var promise = $.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: 'ajax.php?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
                       async: false,
                       cache: false,
                       data : {
                           ddw_order_date: ddw_order_date,
                           id_timeslot: self.timeSlotId
                       },
                       dataType : "json",
                       complete: function(d) {

                       },
                       success: function(jsonData) {
                          if(!jsonData || jsonData == 0){
                             return false;
                          }else{return jsonData;}
                       },

                    });
```

por não saber como estar o seu JSON não tenho como dar a certeza mas o que posso falar é que você seguindo meu exemplo você vai conseguir , bons estudos . Caso o return false não trave use o  e.preventDefault(); lógico passando o evento .

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu a raiz do meu problema, pois não é o retorno que está com problema, suponha que meu PHP seja igual ao seu, `jsonData.mensagem`, não iria mudar nada a interação com o evento do botão, é aí que está o problema. mesmo que eu fizesse assim, ainda estaria dentro do promise... entende.

Comment: Vou publicar um exemplo similar do problema no jsfiddle para vc entender...

Comment: OK, manda o exemplo mais tarde tento te ajudar .