# Função retorna uma string no lugar de uma promise

Tags: javascript, jquery

O código abaixo retorna uma promessa:

```
function getDealerships(region) {
    return $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/v1/dealerships?region=" + region
    });
}
```

Assim posso esperar pela reposta do servidor e processar o resultado:

```
var dealerships = getDealerships('sul');
dealerships.done(function(data){
    //...
});
```

O problema é que preciso implementar um sistema simples de cache e assim evitar que o servidor seja consultado no caso do utilizador escolher a mesma região:

```
var dealershipsCache = [];

function getDealerships(region) {
    if ( region in  dealershipsCache )
        return dealershipsCache[region];

    return $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/v1/dealerships?region=" + region
    });
}
```

Repare que se a região estiver em cache, é retornado o respectivo valor, porém o que se espera é uma promessa e não uma string.

Como resolver o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de criar uma Promise "falsa", ie que dá retorno imediato caso `region in dealershipsCache` dê verdadeiro, para `getDealerships` dar sempre uma Promise como resultado.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
var dealershipsCache = [];

function getDealerships(region) {
    return new Promise(function(res, fail) {
        if (region in dealershipsCache) {
            res(dealershipsCache[region]);
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "/api/v1/dealerships?region=" + region,
                success: function(response) {
                    res(response);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Se precisas de usar tecnologia anterior a Promises, e assim suportar browsers antigos, podes fazer assim, com callbacks:

```
var dealershipsCache = {};
function getDealerships(region, done) {
    if (region in dealershipsCache) {
        return done(dealershipsCache[region]);
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/api/v1/dealerships?region=" + region,
            success: function(response) {
                done(response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

e depois chamas assim:

```
getDealerships('brazil', function(res){
    // e aqui podes usar a resposta
});
```

Comment: Eu fiz uma solução semelhante em angular. Várias chamadas que eram feitas em HTTP eu refiz com uma promise que retornava o mesmo objeto response, funcionou bem

Comment: Vale lembrar que tem que tomar cuidado para que o `fail` seja chamado, caso contrário haverá uma falha silenciosa na execução da `Promise`.

Comment: Sergio, segundo a documentação não funciona no IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility  e preciso mesmo considerar o IE.

Comment: Veja se [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135516/como-travar-submiss%C3%A3o-atrav%C3%A9s-de-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-por-um-evento-bind-em-bot) te ajuda.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes juntei uma solução para Browsers mais antigos, à moda antiga (que eu prefiro ainda hoje).

Answer (score 1):

Para transformar um valor em uma `Promise` que houve sucesso de resposta, basta você encapsular o valor com `Promise.resolve`.

```
var dealershipsCache = [];

function getDealerships(region) {
    if ( region in  dealershipsCache )
        return Promise.resolve(dealershipsCache[region]);

    return $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/v1/dealerships?region=" + region
    });
}
```

Solução com `jQuery.Deferred`:

```
var dealershipsCache = [];

function getDealerships(region) {
    var defer = null;
    if ( region in  dealershipsCache ) {
        defer = $.Deferred();
        defer.resolve(dealershipsCache[region]);
        return defer.promise();
    }

    return $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/v1/dealerships?region=" + region
    });
}
```

Solução com `$.fn.promise` [NOTA: em algumas versões mais antigas essa solução não irá funcionar):

```
var dealershipsCache = [];

function getDealerships(region) {
    if ( region in  dealershipsCache ) {
        return $(dealershipsCache[region]).promise().then(function(elements) {
          return elements[0];
        });
    }

    return $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/v1/dealerships?region=" + region
    });
}
```

Comment: mas segundo a documentação, Promise não funciona no IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Amigo, sua pergunta pede por Promise, não por "Promise do jQuery", formule melhor sua pergunta então... mas enfim, até que versão do IE precisa dar suporte? Veja se isto serve: https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise

Comment: Gabriel, está lá na tag jquery, inclusive o exemplo utiliza jquery, o que não deixa de ser uma promise.

Comment: O cache precisa ser o valor em si, não pode ser a "Promise jQuery"?